# Unidentified best bounty hunter?

Tags: discussion, bounties, data-explorer

So... I'm having fun with the data explorer running various queries to explore the data and when I run [this query to check who got the most reputation out of bounties](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1080/top-users-by-number-of-bounties-won#resultSets), the user ID with most bounties won shows no user.

Is that a result of unawarded bounties? Any other explanations?

Comment: Must be a result of community stepping in to auto award bounties?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Considering that you're selecting `Posts.OwnerUserId` as the Id to use for the user link, by that field being *empty* (or null, whatever), you can correctly infer that the **post is not owned by anyone**. This occurs when a user has been deleted or disassociated from a post.

Therefore, 344 posts have been awarded a bounty, where their owner no longer exists.

Comment: It is a nullable field... and `empty != null`. :P

Comment: @hichris123 That assumes that when a user gets deleted the field's value actually gets changed to NULL and not just an empty string, though. I don't care to investigate it.

Comment: Thanks! I figured it was null but I did not realize that if multiple users did not exist anymore it would all end up in the same bunch. Just for the record, I'm definitely not knowledgeable to make up that type of stuff, I just ran someone else's query in the data explorer out of curiosity. Trying to learn my way around to make sense of the data. Fun stuff! :-)